# Continuity and differentiability of f(x,y) at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $f$ be a function defined by
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} \dfrac{\sin x - \sin y}{x-y} & x \neq y \\ \cos x & x = y \end{cases}$$
Study the continuity and differentiability of $f$ in the origin.

Comment: Use that $\sin(x)-\sin(y)=2\cos((x+y)/2)\sin((x-y)/2)$. With this $\frac{\sin(x)-\sin(y)}{x-y}=\cos((x+y)/2)\frac{\sin((x-y)/2)}{(x-y)/2}$. When $(x,y)\to(0,0)$ from inside the set $x\neq y$, we have that $\cos((x+y)/2)\to 1$ and $\frac{\sin((x-y)/2)}{(x-y)/2}\to1$ since $(x-y)/2\to0$. Along $x=y$ you also have that $f(x,y)\to 1=\cos(0)=f(1,1)$. So, $f$ is continuous at $(0,0)$.